# Why my "friends_list" remains empty when my Django signal is triggered?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-signals

I am using a Django `post_save` signal to modify the Database content of `Budget`. In my response I get the `friendsList` filled with the user IDs, but when I use post_save signals and query and store it in `friends_list` I see that the list remains empty.

My response:

```
{
    "id": 5,
    "amount": 100,
    "budgetForSplitPay": 1,
    "friendsList": [
      2,
      3
    ]
  }
```

My post_save signal code:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=SplitPayBudget)
def post_save_splitpay_amount(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    Budget.objects.filter(user=instance.budgetForSplitPay.user).update(budgetofUser=F('budgetofUser') - instance.amount)
    friends_list = instance.friendsList.all()

    for friend in friends_list:
        Budget.objects.filter(user=friend.user).update(budgetofUser=F('budgetofUser') - instance.amount)
```

My model:

```
class SplitPayBudget(models.Model):
    budgetForSplitPay = models.ForeignKey(Budget, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='budgetForSplitPay')
    friendsList = models.ManyToManyField(Budget, related_name='friendsList', blank=True)
    amount = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.budgetForSplitPay.user)
```

My API call body which triggers this signal:

```
{
  "budgetForSplitPay": "1",
  "amount": 100,
  "friendsList": [2, 3]
}
```

My serializer:

```
class SplitPayBudgetSerializer(ModelSerializer): # Actually a TransactionSerializer
    class Meta:
        model = SplitPayBudget
        fields = '__all__'
```

I want a solutions by which my `friends_list` should be initialised with `[2, 3]`.

Thank You.

I tried using `friends_list = instance.friendsList.all()` but the `instance.friendsList.all()` remains empty.

Comment: Your field is `m2m`. `post_save` will not be triggered on updating m2m. Your signal should be `m2m_changed`.

Comment: @Lax_Sam can you describe how to write it with syntax?

Comment: @Lax_Sam post_save is getting triggered and 1st line of function ```Budget.objects.filter(user=instance.budgetForSplitPay.user).update(budgetofUser=F('budgetofUser') - instance.amount)``` is getting updated

Comment: How are you saving the friends_list field?

Comment: Did you change the post_save to m2m_changed?

Comment: @Lax_Sam yes and then used post_add action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved my problem by taking @Lax_Sam's hint. Used `m2m_changed` and `post_add` action.

Signal Code:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=SplitPayBudget)
def post_save_splitpay_amount(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    Budget.objects.filter(user=instance.budgetForSplitPay.user).update(budgetofUser=F('budgetofUser') - instance.amount)

    
@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=SplitPayBudget.friendsList.through)
def update_budget_for_splitpay(sender, instance, action, **kwargs):
    if action == 'post_add':
        for friend in instance.friendsList.all():
            Budget.objects.filter(user=friend.user).update(budgetofUser=F('budgetofUser') - instance.amount)
```